# I try using Provider read methods to add desired stuff but nothing works

Tags: flutter

I have 2 models extending `ChangeNotifier` called `Tabs` and `Views`. `Tabs` for tabs parameter of `TabBar` an `Views` for `TabBarView`.

models:

**Tabs.dart**

```
 class Tabs with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Widget> _tabs = [Text('Today')];
  List<Widget> get tabs => _tabs;

  void addTabs(String text) {
    _tabs.add(Tab(text: text));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removetabs(String text) {
    _tabs.remove(Tab(text: text));
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Views.dart**

```
class Views with ChangeNotifier {
final List<Widget> _views = [Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100, width: 100,)];
  List<Widget> get views => _views;
  void addView(Widget widget) {
    _views.add(widget);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Tabs>(create: (_) => Tabs()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Views>(create: (_) => Views()),
  ],
  builder:(context, child)=> MaterialApp(.......);
```

So for both `TabBar` and `TabBarView` I `watch` or listen to the List `tabs` and `views` model variables and that works perfectly fine as I tried adding hard coded widgets to these 2 variables.
However, Provider `read` method doesn't work when I try adding a tab or view.
  `final tabs = Tabs().tabs; final views = Views().views;`

```
AppBar(bottom: tabs.isNotEmpty
              ? TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                  tabs: context.watch<Tabs>().tabs,
                )
              : null),

body: tabs.isNotEmpty
          ? TabBarView(children: context.watch<Views>().views)
          : appLogo,
```

**adding tabs and views**

So in my app I first query firebase docs and if there isn't any doc I want to add one with the date 'Today' and then add to the tabs and views model variable that I created but nothing get added to these 2 lists.

```
Future addTabsViews() async {
  try{
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> query = await todosRef.limit(1).get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));

  if (query.docs.isEmpty) {
    Map<String, dynamic> todayDoc = {
      'todo': null,
      'subTask': null,
      'isChecked': null,
      'date': 'Today'
    };
    await todosRef.add(todayDoc);
    context.read<Tabs>().addTabs(todayDoc['date']);
    context.read<Views>().addView(Container());
    print(tabs);
    print(views);
  } } on FirebaseException catch (e){
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

I call this `future` in the `initState`;
Been stuck in this error for days and can't fix it until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your tabs and views that you reference like this, you are creating new objects and not referencing the same that you use in your provider.

> final tabs = Tabs().tabs;

> final views = Views().views;

To get the Tabs instance from the provider and listen to any updates you have to get it like this e.g.:

> var tabs = Provider.of(context).tabs;

You can now use `tabs` from the provider and they will update when you `notifyListeners();`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tabs = Provider.of<Tabs>(context).tabs;
    var views = Provider.of<Views>(context).views;
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(bottom: tabs.isNotEmpty ? TabBar(tabs: tabs) : null),
      body: tabs.isNotEmpty ? TabBarView(children: views) : FlutterLogo(),
    );
}
```